# PixelSense Surface 2.0 - Drag and drop out of a UserControl onto a ScatterView and vice-versa

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pixelsense

Previously I tried to Drag and Drop an object out of a `LibraryContainer` onto a `ScatterView` and vice-versa and it was rather simple being that the `LibraryContainer`, `LibraryStack` and `LibraryBar` support drag and drop events by default. That combined with the `DragDropScatterView.cs` from the ShoppingCart example provided with the Surface 2.0 SDK was pretty straightforward.

Now I want to be able to drag and drop a `UserControl` onto a `ScatterView`4 and vice-versa, i.e., something like this: http://goo.gl/zZIdg.

From what I researched there is a way to do that and can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727736.aspx. However, here they don't use the `DragDropScatterView.cs`, it's done a different way. You have two `ObservableCollections` (a source and a target), the `ScatterViewItems` and the `SurfaceListBox`.

One thing I don't like in this example is that the `ScatterViewItems` that can be dragged don't really have a scale property because when the user clicks on the `ScatterViewItem`, it creates a visual style and hides the `ScatterViewItem` and when you drop it, it updates the coordinates and orientation of that `ScatterViewItem` and makes it visible. I decided not to go this way, since I want a normal `ScatterViewItem` behaviour.

The basic thing I want to do is to have, for example a `Label`, and on the side a `ScatterView` and be able to drag that `Label` (creating a visual cursor - already done) and drop it on the `ScatterView`, creating a `ScatterViewItem` that has the same properties as the original `Label`. I tried doing this with the `DragDropScatterView.cs` but when I'm using a `Label` my `droppingCursor.Data` (on the `DragDropScatterView.cs`) is `null` and I think that happens because the `draggedElement.DataContext` (on the `LabelView.xaml.cs`) is also `null`, however this is not `null` when I have a `SurfaceListBox`.

I provide a code sample here: http://sdrv.ms/VDuHq5. In the `SurfaceWindow1.xaml` there is the `TagVisualization` and the container of the `ScatterView`, the `LabelView.xaml` is called inside the `` `TagVisualization ``.

If someone can help me on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem and here is a brief explanation on how I did it:

I searched and found [this](http://goo.gl/N0IjW). I then used this `SurfaceListBox` with these drag and drop events and combined it with the `DragDropScatterView` class, so each time a new `ScatterViewItem` was created I would have a normal `ScatterView` control of my custom object. With this method you also have to create a Visual Cursor, i.e., what you'll see when you'e dragging the item from the `SurfaceListBox`.

The thing that was puzzling me and that Serge Calderara (from the MSDN Surface Forum) helped me with, was that I kept trying to associate these drag and drop events to a `Label` for example, or a `UserControl` even, but I was looking at things the wrong way. In most cases the best solution for you is to have a container, and in that container you put the `UserControls` you want and you only associate the drag and drop events to that container, and not to each individual item. With that in mind it was rather easy to put things together, I created my `UserControls` and populated the `SurfaceListBox` (wich is my container) with an `ItemTemplateSelector` and I used that same Selector for the `ScatterView` (that's receiving the items from the container). In my object class I just defined a variable to save which type of `UserControl` I'll have and return the `DataTemplate` accordingly.

With this I created a `SurfaceListBox` with two custom UserControls that I can drag and drop to a `ScatterView` and back. A working sample with MVVM pattern can be found here: http://sdrv.ms/10SjKaH.

I hope it can help others and it helped me. If you have any questions or suggestions please feel free to ask/tell.